# sorting vector of pointers by two parameters

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am trying to sort a vector of pointers to a class A using std::sort, but am having some difficulties.

Imagine class A beings just a point, containing x and y coordinates. I want to sort the vector by y coordinates from biggest to lowest using some fixed offset value. And on top of this I want to sort it by x coordinatex, from lowest to biggest. I've had something like following in mind but as you can imagine its not working as wanted:

```
bool A::sortByCoordinates(const A *a, const A *b)
{
    if ((b->y < a->y - offset) || (b->y > a->y + offset)) {
        return false;
    } else if (b->x < a->x) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


void A::recalculate(std::vector<A *> &test)
{
    std::sort(test.begin(), test.end(), sortByCoordinates);
}
```

In short, if `b->y < a->y - offset` or `b->y > a->y + offset` treat it as `b->y == a->y` and then sort by their x coordinates from lowest to biggest. If the above is not true sort it as `b->y < a->y`.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Imagine a xy plane such as this: [image: plane]

where black dots represent class A with x and y coordinates. I want to split this plane into finitely many sections which are represented by the red lines and are wide as `offset`. Now I want to treat points in these sections as tho they had the same y coordinate and sort them only by their x coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(b->y < a->y - offset) || (b->y > a->y + offset)
```

These are two different cases, which should have different results. I suppose that `b` is "less" then `a` in first case, and "greater" in the other case, but your code returns false for both cases. See @Jonathan's answer on how to fix this.

---

But also note a that your approach (considering all y's that differ by less than  `offset` equal) has a major flaw: it will not generate a [strict total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). Assume you have `offset=3` and three points `A(x=0,y=0)`, `B(x=-2,y=2)` and `C(x=-4,y=4)`.

You will have `A` and `B` falling within `offset` by `y` coordinate so you will compare `A.x` and `B.x` and get `A<B`. Similarly you get `B<C`, but `A` and `C` do not fall within `offset` distance, so you get `A>C`, that is `A<B<C<A`, which should never be. (Tweak the coordinates if I get your ordering wrong). Therefore you first need to reconsider your ordering concept.

---

If (as you specify in the edit) you want to divide into horizontal stripes, and sort points within a stripe by x, then you should not check whether the `y`s differ by no more than `offset`, because two points can have their `y`s differ by less then `offset`, but still be located in different stripes. I would suggest to explicitly calculate the stripe number and compare them, something like

```
bool A::sortByCoordinates(const A& a, const A& b)
{
    // get stripe numbers, assuming A::y to be positive int
    int stripeA = a.y / offset; // be careful if a.y can be negative!
    int stripeB = b.y / offset;
    if (stripeA != stripeB)
        return stripeA < stripeB;
    return a.x < b.x;
}
```

Comment: x, y and offset are all integers. Could your code be simplified by knowing this?

Comment: @user1806687, see edit, but be careful as `operator/` for `int`s has a weird behavior around zero, so you will most probably have to add a separate `if` for negative (or positive) numbers.

Comment: No worries, all of those are always positive and bigger than 0. I will try your code later on.

Comment: These results doesnt seem right to me: 

 -- x=922,y=20
 -- x=906,y=35
 -- x=969,y=35
 -- x=996,y=25
 -- x=1006,y=24
 -- x=928,y=39
 -- x=835,y=70
 -- x=901,y=78

Comment: @user1806687 , and what is your offset?

Comment: I have offset set to 12.

Comment: @user1806687, why are you surprized then? The first stripe is from 0 to 11, the second from 12 to 23, and so on. You then have: `(922,20)` --- second stripe; `(906, 35), (969, 35), (996, 25), (1006, 24)` --- third stripe; `(835, 70)` --- 6th stripe; `(910, 78)` --- 7th stripe. Everything seems correct.